# Create a user with specific privilges

Tags: 16.04, 13.04

I want to add user in my os , so that he can 
do coding , execute programs , browse the internet , install eclipse software but should not be aware of root users name (like guest session)
and change or update the system software and settings 
(run commands like sudo apt-get update or upgrade).

Comment: well, the root user's name is of course root, unless you change it. Users need access to /etc/passwd , so there is no way to hide other users on the system. Nothing you ask for (coding, execute programs, or browse the internet) requires root priviliges. I am not sure about eclipse, but if you give them access to sudo, or sudo apt only, then they can install or remove what they want. Perhaps you want to give your user a VM

Comment: I want to create a user who is not the root but he can install eclipse do coding , browse the internet . Is it possible ? or else shall I download eclipse off-line installer and begin the installation as root ? In both the cases I want to create a user who is not the root .

Comment: This  is the reason  why I want to create a user who is not the root https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2360260

Comment: Just make a user and install eclipse or anything she needs for her